# Migrating to Node.js from ExactTarget's PHP starter kit

Tags: marketing-cloud, php, node.js

I wrote a custom class based off of ExactTarget's PHP [starter-kit](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/api_starter_kits/) to manage our newsletters sign-ups, it gets the job done. Problem is, my company wants to outsource this task to a third party, it appears they're gonna use Node.js so management in my company has asked me to try porting our class to Node.js. The following is an excerpt of the class which retrieves subscriptions for a given email address:

```
/*****************************************
|
| Create Client
|
*****************************************/
private function getClient()
{
  $wsdl = $this->wsdl;

  /* Create the Soap Client */
  $client = new ExactTargetSoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>1));

  /* Set username and password for the account here */
  $client->username = $this->userName;
  $client->password = $this->pwd;

  return $client;
}

/*****************************************
|
| Retrieve subscriber data based on email
|
*****************************************/
public function retrieve()
{

   try{

     /* Create the Soap Client */
     $client = $this->getClient();

     $rr = new ExactTargetRetrieveRequest();
     $rr->ObjectType = "DataExtensionObject[{$this->externalKey}]";//name of the data extension
     $rr->Properties =  $this->newslTypes;
     $rr->Properties[] = "Email";

       // Setup a simple filter based on the key column you want to match on
     $sfp= new ExactTargetSimpleFilterPart();
     $sfp->Value =  array($this->data['email']);
     $sfp->SimpleOperator = ExactTargetSimpleOperators::equals;
     $sfp->Property="Email";

     $rr->Filter = new \SoapVar(
      $sfp, 
      SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,
      'SimpleFilterPart',
      "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI"
      );
     $rr->Options = NULL;
     $rrm = new ExactTargetRetrieveRequestMsg();
     $rrm->RetrieveRequest  = $rr;
     $results = $client->Retrieve($rrm);

     /* Output the results */
     return json_encode($results);

   } catch (SoapFault $e) {

     return json_encode($e);
   }

}
```

So how can I port the above code to Node.js ?

I've taken a look to [node-fuel](https://github.com/ExactTarget/node-fuel) but I have a hunch I would have to write the client myself or that it's meant for something totally different, I emphasize just a hunch. I could have no idea what I'm talking about, but I thought try asking anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Seems a little unreasonable to me that a vendor who is choosing to use Node.js is then asking you to do some of their work for them... I would point them to the generic API documentation and leave them to use whichever [SOAP client package](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=soap+client) they prefer. Or is the same functionality available via a REST API? If so node-fuel the "Node.js client for ExactTarget's Fuel REST APIs" would probably be the easiest way to go from JavaScript (assuming it covers the required API).

Comment: My employer instructed me to try so :/

Comment: Getting paid to learn new stuff - always a good thing. I find [egghead.io](https://egghead.io/technologies/node) great for quick intros.